# What is this component labelled DZP?

Tags: audio, identification, reverse-engineering

I'm reverse engineering this basic circuit, but I'm not entirely sure what the package TDF6 in the top right corner is or does. My guess was Zener diodes for voltage spikes. The label DZP is also something I've never seen before.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Do you have the physical device that goes with the circuit diagram? Is there also a DZP1?

Comment: Sounds like "Diode Zener Protection", i.e. a TVS or Transient Voltage Suppressor.

Comment: DZ is sometimes used for zener diodes and TVS is a kind of zener. Maybe it's some diode array.

Comment: @rdtsc Yes, I think you're right. I'll just implement it myself then. Thanks for helping me (and Lundin too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sounds like "Diode Zener Protection", i.e. a TVS or Transient Voltage
> Suppressor.

> ...it's some diode array

Courtesy of @Lublin and @rdtsc